# I have a PC with PTSD, how should fear effects work?

Tags: gm-techniques, conditions, fear

She’s a first time player & struggled to come up with a backstory. She brought up having amnesia caused by trauma.

After playing for a couple of sessions, hearing the more experienced players’ backstories & seeing how they wove into the campaign, she asked if I could come up with a cool backstory for her to discover as they played. I did, & if I do say so myself, it’s very cool.

However, it requires her to have a trigger, specifically with dragons. (Yes, she agreed to having something that triggered memories of trauma)I only plan on them facing dragons two or three times, to introduce the trigger and therefore the root of her PTSD, and then to face the fear and reveal the backstory.

All that said, how best to work fear effects with this? Our first dragon encounter is coming up, and I was thinking that as they arrived at the dragon’s cave to have her roll against a higher DC to avoid being shaken, and as they moved closer to the dragon or inside the cave, continue with rolls with higher DCs, adding in bits and pieces of memories, and if she becomes panicked, having a partial flashback. This is effective, and will work, I’m wondering if there is a better way, more creative option, just ideas in general.

Comment: What game & edition are you playing?

Answer (score 12):

Based on your vocabulary I would guess you are playing D&D, but it doesn't really matter for my answer:

You said the PC has PTSD from a dragon enounter they don't remember. And you are wondering what that means in terms to *another* dragon encounter.

But the point of PTSD is not how a person reacts in the same situation again. The point is that there are harmless things that trigger their trauma.

Imagine a war veteran that hit a landmine with their vehicle. PTSD doesn't mean they lead a happy life if they never hit another landmine. It means that all kinds of normal and harmless things trigger their trauma. Maybe a bump in the road. A door slamming. Hearing the song that played on the radio when they had that traumatic event. A TV ad with exploding cars. If they would only react to the original incident repeating, we would not call that PTSD. We call that normal.

So if this PC has PTSD, it should manifest with harmless things that trigger their trauma. Maybe a chicken flapping it's wings on the market. A roar of air and fire through a chimney. A mage casting a fire breathing spell. Seeing a lizard or crocodile. Normal things, that hint and foreshadow what is about to come.

Modifying a DC as a result of a backstory is not only falling short of decsribing PTSD, it's boring. On so many levels. First it's plain mechanics, no roleplaying. Then it makes this PC more susceptible to losing control over their character. But agency, the ability to act, is key in having fun in a game.

So whatever you want to do with the dragon, don't leave it to dice or mechanics. It's their *story*. It should be a story, not a game of dice. They should have their story moment, even if they roll natural 20s all evening and would not be shaken at all.

So what you should do is drop the mechanics. It's their *story*. Decide what will happen if they come close. Tell them. Let them play their character and react to that.

If you have players that are exceptionally bad at the roleplaying aspect of roleplaying, you may want to invent mechanics for that. But make it memorable and make it so it definetely happens, regardless of how they roll. Otherwise you will sit there and Murphy willing, they will roll too good for their own story. That defeats the goal of telling a good story together.

Comment: +1, drop the mechanics! Maybe just pass the player a note with texts like, "a chicken flaps it wings, it reminds you of the dragon landing", and letting the player choose what to do with that.